# Powershell WMI query CIM_DataFile doesn't work for all extensions

Tags: file, powershell, wmi

This works:

```
Get-wmiobject -query "select * from CIM_datafile where name like '%.txt' and drive='e:'"
```

This doesn't:

```
Get-wmiobject -query "select * from CIM_datafile where name like '%.zip' and drive='e:'"
```

Both work using WBEMtest:

```
select * from CIM_datafile where name like '%.zip' and drive='e:'
select * from CIM_datafile where name like '%.txt' and drive='e:'
```

Does anyone know why this happens? Anyone have a work around? I would like to search for a number of file extensions without having to use gci.

Comment: You query against zip files works for me, I just tried. So the problem is not the query.    Get-wmiobject -query "select * from CIM_datafile where name like '%.zip' and drive='e:'"

Comment: Weird. When trying this on a Windows 2008 r2 server it doesn't work. When I tried it on win 7 on the c drive I got the expected results. I have administrative access on both machines.

Comment: You need to provide more details like what was the output when it didn't work.

Comment: There was no output, it returns as if it was unable to find anything. I believe this is some sort of permissions related thing though I am not sure how it comes into play because I have local admin privileges.

Comment: Also it doesn't return all the .txt's either. Just some of them. I think this is a permissions issue but I am not sure if there is a work around.